# Changing UIBezierPath scale when tableview is editing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a `UITableView` with custom tableview cells and each cell has a `UIView` with a unique `UIBezierPath` inside.  My `UIView` stretches across my tableview cell with some spacing on both ends so it does not lead off the screen.  My problem is that when my tableview goes into editing mode, my cells shift to the right and a portion of the view containing the path goes beyond the window.

I'm able to change the width of the UIView during the shift by doing:

```
- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super didTransitionToState:state];

    if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) 
    {
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.waveView.frame.origin.x, self.waveView.frame.origin.y, self.waveView.frame.size.width -100, self.waveView.frame.size.height);

        //I chose -100 just to test it out

        self.waveView.frame = newFrame;

    }
}
```

However, when doing the above, my path continues to go beyond the view and window.  Whats the best way to resolve this?  I believe scaling the bezier path is an option but that redraws the path, which causes some lag and reduces the frames per second in the animation when transitioning from edit and non-edit mode since I'm redrawing multiple paths.  Here is the scale code I tried:

```
    CGFloat scaleFactor = (self.waveView.frame.size.width-100)/self.waveView.frame.size.width;

    self.waveView.frame = newFrame;

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.waveView.transform,
                                                         scaleFactor,
                                                         1);

    [self.waveView.path applyTransform:transform];
```

Comment: If you are added, in your custom cell, the new view inside it. (That´s [self addSubview:self.waveView]). Change to this: [self.contentView addSubview:self.waveView]. ContentView resize automatically with enter in editing mode. (The only thing you could need it's add some constraints).

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem. The `UIBezierPath` coordinates should already be relative to the `UIView` containing it and the `UIView` should be embedded within the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`. If the embedded `UIView` has constraints that causes it to re-size with the `contentView` doesn't the `UIBezierPath` automatically re-size?

Comment: @OnikIV the `UIView` is already a `subView` of `contentView`.  I can see in the xib file of the `tableViewCell` that the `UIView` is within `contentView`.

Comment: @RoboticCat the `UIBezierPath` is created earlier on in the program.  It is only when I reach the view controller with the `tableView` that the `UIBezierPath` is added to the `UIView`.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I do `cell.waveView.path = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:pathData];` which sets the `UIBezierPath` created from earlier.  So as of now, when the width of `UIView` is changed, the `UIBezierPath` remains the same size.

Comment: @Brosef If in your xib you have added the constraints between your UIView and the Content View, when you enter en editing mode it's sure than your UIView will be resize. And Probably you need see te relationship between the bezierPath and it's view.

Comment: @Brosef: You have a logic problem. The coordinates of the `UIBezierPath` are absolute and are based on whatever absolute coordinates you initially used to create it. So when you re-draw it it uses the original path coordinates which seem to be bigger than the `UIView` you are drawing it into. I think you will need to re-create the bezier path (before adding it to the new tablecell view) scaling the absolute coordinates so that it fits into the new view. You should already know what "size" you used when originally creating it. Once drawn to the bounds of the new `UIView` it should scale OK.

Comment: @OnikIV I haven't implemented auto layout for the tableview cell yet so there are no constraints as of yet.

Comment: @RoboticCat You're right.  The issue with redrawing the path is that I will have to redraw the path of all the cells visible in the tableview, causing some major lag.  I think a better option would be to create a `UIImage` of the path and displaying the image inside the view instead of the path.

Comment: @Brosef: Creating a `UIImage` will work but you'll need to test the re-sizing / aspect changes to make sure they're acceptable. A static `UIImage` will certainly be faster than re-drawing a `UIBezierPath` but you will need to check your FPS using Instruments to see if using `UIBezierPath`s is a real problem. Also, if you have to create a very large number of images and cache them in an array your memory    usage will rise dramatically (i.e. 1000 images * 1MB is approximately 1GB memory required).

Comment: @RoboticCat I'll do more investigating to see if the drawing really causes the lag.  If I take the `UIImage` path, I'm assuming the images will be pretty small.  More like KB rather than MB.  I'd prefer not to use images though.